# How scaleable is drools in applying rules over millions of transactions?

Tags: drools, rules

I would like to know the processing time and scaleability of drools engine, when I've a situation to apply 50+ rules over millions of transactions. Any suggestions would throw light on this aspect.

Comment: Vague terms like "transaction" and "millions" and no indication whatsoever of the nature of your rules permits only one answer: Benchmark it.

Answer (score 0):

Drools does not follow scale out architecture. I did not do performance analysis as of now with drools. But as per the stats published for various rule engines, drools scores more than others.